# django rest framework: how generate schema from serializer types?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I added the `django-rest-swagger` to my django-rest-framework project, following the instructions. The GUI looks fine, but the request description, which seems to be automatically generated from the `APIView`s `get_serializer` field has some issues. Specifically

- nested objects are ignored, and shows as `{}`
- all `string` types are just listed as `string`, ignoring the openapi `format` field

So, for example, for this serializer

```
class NestedSerializer(Serializer):
    firstname = StringField()

class RequestSerializer(Serializer):
    name = NestedSerializer()
    date = DateField()
    choice = ChoiceField(['aa', 'bb', 'cc'])
```

the GUI shows the request as

```
name: {}
date: string
choice: string
```

Am I missing something, or the project really doesn't support more specific types?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have imported proper serializers Fields. 
It looks like `StringField()` is not included into `rest_framework.serializers` package.

What's more `django-rest-swagger` is marked as deprecated. As the owner of the [`django-rest-swagger`](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger#django-rest-swagger-deprecated-2019-06-04) repo [`django-rest-swagger`](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger#django-rest-swagger-deprecated-2019-06-04) written you should use [drf-yasg](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg) which supports both:

- nested serializers
- `ChoiceField()`